Bias estimation (after reversing the log transformation) in parameter estimation of fractional Brownian motion
I am learning these two literature,
1 [SIMULATION AND IDENTIFICATION OF THE FRACTIONAL B ROWNIAN MOTION : A BIBLIOGRAPHICAL AND COMPARATIVE STUDY COEURJOLLY Jean-François]
2 [Estimating the Parameters of a Fractional Brownian Motion by Discrete Variations of its Sample Paths JEAN-FRANÇOIS COEURJOLLY]
and I stuck at a understanding the bias for the scaling parameters $C$ of the fBm. This parameter $C$ is obtained by doing log transformation to the data (to obtain linearity), performed OLS and then transform back.
Therefore, the estimator for $C$ is a biased estimator.
I checked the code on how the author estimate the bias but I could not figure out exactly what the author was doing as bias estimation was not mentioned in both literature.
I can tell from the code, the author was trying to use asymptotic variance to estimate the variance but it does not match the below variance formula exactly
I paste the relevant part of the literature and code below. The code seems to use the asymptotic expansion of Digamma function.
So I want to ask what sort of bias correction is performing here? and if possible, why the Digamma function's expansion is here?



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This appears to be a correction for the retransformation problem using Duan's smearing estimator.
